# Scroll horizontal en Select para cualquier navegador

Tags: html, css, navegador-web

Quiero añadir un scroll horizontal en un elemento select. El código que os muestro a continuación funciona adecuadamente en chrome, sin embargo no funciona en firefox ni ie.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"> 
</head> 
    <body> 
        <select id="select" name="select" size ='3'>
          <option value="value1">LUNES</option> 
          <option value="value2">MARTES</option>
          <option value="value3">MIERCOLES</option>
        </select>
    </body> 
</html>
```

y el siguiente css:

```
.select{
     width: 100px; 
     overflow: auto;
     height: 70px; 
}
```

Si alguien conoce una solución común para todos los navegadores lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Todos los navegadores? ¿Cuáles y qué versiones mínimas?

Answer (score 1):

Deberias usar

```
#select{
     width: 100px; 
     overflow: auto;
     height: 70px; 
   }
```

El símbolo numeral (gato) indica que buscas el elemento que lleve select como valor de su atributo **id**

O en su defecto

```
select{
         width: 100px; 
         overflow: auto;
         height: 70px; 
       }
```

Sin punto eso indica que vas a afectar a todos los elementos select

Answer (score 0):

Podrias solucionarlo con un contenedor con scroll horizontal como caja padre.

Codigo CSS

```
#select_list{
    width: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Codigo HTML

```
<div id="select_list"> 
    <select id="select" name="select" size ='3'>
       <option value="value1">LUNES</option> 
       <option value="value2">MARTES</option>
       <option value="value3">MIERCOLES</option>
    </select>
</div>
```